# Problems with Serializing an Object Java

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have a tablelayout which implements serializable which keeps tablerows. in the tablerows, it will contain an edittext and a checkbox, much like a checklist to be exact.

However when I try serializing the tablelayout (CheckList) it tells me the that the tablerows are not serizable. I have after which implemented it to be serializable too. But it then, tells me that the EditText and CheckBox are not serializable.

How can I solve this?

UPDATE: (Serializer.java)

```
public class Serializer {

public static byte[] serializeObject(Object o) { 
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 

    try { 
      ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos); 
      out.writeObject(o); 
      out.close(); 

      // Get the bytes of the serialized object 
      byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray(); 

      return buf; 
    } catch(IOException ioe) { 
      Log.e("serializeObject", "error", ioe); 

      return null; 
    } 
}

  public static Object deserializeObject(byte[] b) { 
    try { 
      ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(b)); 
      Object object = in.readObject(); 
      in.close(); 

      return object; 
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) { 
      Log.e("deserializeObject", "class not found error", cnfe); 

      return null; 
    } catch(IOException ioe) { 
      Log.e("deserializeObject", "io error", ioe); 

      return null; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

This is how I serialized the checklist:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("checklist", Serializer.serializeObject(checklist));
        intent.putExtra("checklist", bundle);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
```

And here's how I tried to deserialize it:

```
    try {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bundle checklist_bundle = extras.getBundle("checklist");
                byte[] bytes =  (byte[]) checklist_bundle.getSerializable("checklist");
                CheckList checklist = (CheckList) Serializer.deserializeObject(bytes);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would extend the class, make the extended class serializable , and use that instead.

Not sure what else I can add to make this more substantial, but I guess we can build on it over time? :)

Comment: thanks for your reply. the checklist extends a item class which is something i created, and the item class extends a view class, do you know how can i extend it such a way then?

Comment: I have also added some code to how I serialize and deserialize the CheckList. Hope it will be clearer.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change anything: just make sure that all the classes `implements Serializable`. You shouldn't need to create the read and write methods unless it doesn't work for you in the default way. (I've never had the default way fail on me, honestly!)

Comment: but it tells me that the views such as edittext and checkbox are not serializable. I tried to create a custom version of it, by extending it and implementing serializable, it tells me android.app is not serializable.

Comment: I'm surprised you need a reference to the app in your object... Sounds like an architecture mistake there.

Comment: ohh no!! this is really bad.. i am new to android programming, but this is just for learning purposes. but for now, i am trying out Snicolas solution by implementing Externalizable and with the above serializing and deserializing method it ends up with a InvalidClassException, maybe you help me with this?

Comment: and IllegalAccessException too.

Answer (score 1):

try to mark those fields as [transients or implement Externalizable](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).

Regards,
 Stephane

Comment: thanks for your reply. i tried changing my checklist object to implement Externalizable, but when i tried bundle.getSerializable("checklist"), how am i suppose to deserialize this object so that the final object would be a CheckList object?

Comment: i have added my serializer class in the question.

Comment: I have also added some code to how I serialize and deserialize the CheckList. Hope it will be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

caveat that I have not done any Android programming at all, but I did check the Bundle interface definition for Android.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29

You seem to be calling the wrong stuff. first off:

- no need to create your own serializing/deserializing methods, ditch those, let the JVM serialization engine do the work
- `bundle.putSerializable("checklist", Serializer.serializeObject(checklist));`
  should just be
  `bundle.putSerializable("checklist", checklist);`
  make sure CheckList implements Serializable
- `byte[] bytes =  (byte[]) checklist_bundle.getSerializable("checklist")` should be 
  `CheckList ck =  (CheckList) checklist_bundle.getSerializable("checklist")`
- There was mention above that you have a reference to the "App" from CheckList? I'm not sure what an "App" is, but if it's unserializable, slap a "transient" modifier to its member variable definition in the CheckList class. Note though that during deserialization, you have to properly "fill" that field in. The deserializer won't do that for you automatically (this is where Externalizable can come in)

Answer (score 0):

And what about using the Parcelable interface in Android?